# Open StorageItem in default program in WinRT?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Currently I'm writing a XAML/C#/WinRT Modern UI app, which includes a simple management system of StorageItems of (nearly) arbitrary types, mainly images, PDF/Office documents, text files, ...

Now the best user experience I would get, if I could open a file in the "default program" when the user wants to. Is there any programmatic possibility in C#/WinRT to open a StorageItem with the default program/app (images -> Photos app, pdf -> Reader app, Word/Excel -> Office, ...)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFileAsync(fileToOpen).done(
            function (file) {
                Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file).done(
                    function (success) {
                        // anything you want to do after default program launched        });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think it's that easy ;-)